# Delete button on list view only deletes the last item and not the particular one I want it to delete

Tags: java, android, listview

So I am working with a listview, and I have included a delete button, but whenever I press the delete icon on particular list item, that item does not get deleted, only the last item of the list gets deleted. I have no idea why this is happening. The last item automatically gets deleted, irrespective of whatever item's delete icon I pressed.

This is the code for the Adapter Class :

```
// full subtask adapter code

package com.example.taskmasterv3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SubtaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<subtask> {


    private final Context context;
    private ArrayList<subtask> values;


    public SubtaskAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<subtask> list) {

        //since your are using custom view,pass zero and inflate the custom view by overriding getview

        super(context, 0 , list);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = list;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        //check if its null, if so inflate it, else simply reuse it
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subtask_item, parent, false);
        }

        //use convertView to refer the childviews to populate it with data
        TextView tvSubtaskName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubtaskName);
        ImageView ivPri = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPri);
        ImageView ivTime = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivTime);
        ImageView ivDelete = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivDelete);

        tvSubtaskName.setText(values.get(position).getSubtaskName());

        if (values.get(position).isPriHigh()) {
            ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_high);
        } else if (values.get(position).isPriMed()) {
            ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_med);
        } else if (values.get(position).isPriLow()) {
            ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_low);
        }

        if (values.get(position).isTimeMore()) {
            ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_more);
        } else if (values.get(position).isTimeMed()) {
            ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_med);
        } else if (values.get(position).isTimeLess()) {
            ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_less);
        }


        // Delete button for subtasks (NOT WORKING)

        ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
             SubtaskAdapter.this.remove(SubtaskAdapter.this.getItem(position));

            }
        });

        //return the view you inflated
        return convertView;
    }


    //to keep adding the new subtasks try the following
    public void addANewSubTask(subtask newSubTask){
        ArrayList<subtask> newvalues = new ArrayList<>(this.values);
        newvalues.add(newSubTask);
        this.values = newvalues;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

Comment: not sure what the remove method is like but fro your add new method i can tell you are doing it wrong. remove item from values list then notify adapter that item was removed. same as add. just add and notify added position

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView != null) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subtask_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
holder.ivDelete.setTag(position)
    holder.ivDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int index = (Integer)v.getTag();
    values.remove(index)
    notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Could you please implement this in my code? I am not very experienced so I am facing many issues...